# How to Obtain the `startOfDay` in a `Node.js` Application Running on a UTC Timezone Server

Tags: node.js, nestjs, date-fns, date-fns-tz

I'm trying to get the `startOfDay` of IST (Indian Standard Time) in UTC, on a node app running on ubuntu server where timezone is set to `UTC`

```
  async onModuleInit() {
    const currentUtcTime = new Date();

    // Without date-fns-tz
    const startOfDay1 = startOfDay(currentUtcTime);

    // With date-fns-tz
    const convertedTime = utcToZonedTime(currentUtcTime, 'Asia/Kolkata');
    const startOfDay2 = startOfDay(convertedTime);

    console.log('currentTime :', currentUtcTime);
    console.log(`startDate1 :`, startOfDay1);
    console.log(`startDate2 :`, startOfDay2);
  }
```

this is the result i get

```
currentTime : 2023-09-25T14:46:08.192Z
startDate1 : 2023-09-25T00:00:00.000Z
startDate2 : 2023-09-25T00:00:00.000Z
```

but the start date should be `2023-09-24T18:30:00.000Z`. if i set my `TZ='Asia/Kolkata'` and run the node app, i do get `2023-09-24T18:30:00.000Z` but my server runs on `UTC`.

Am i handling it the right way? can someone guide me here?

Comment: Are you sure your server is IST? you should check your timezone in your server with command `timedatectl`

Comment: my server is in `UTC`

Comment: yeah, that's why you always get UTC time, you should use             `.toLocaleString('sv-SE', { timeZone: 'Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh' })`
something like this, or you have to use moment-timezone 
like this `moment().tz('Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh')`